# Mail does not "reply all": Removes CC addresses if they are in your own "accounts"?

Tags: mail.app

Alice and Bob share a computer. They both have email accounts in Mail. Charlie sends an email to them both:

`To: Alice
Cc: Bob`

Alice gets it and hits "Reply All" and Mail opens a new message composition window:

`To: Charlie`

Bob is removed. Why? Because Apple thinks it's silly to reply to yourself. It knows Bob has an email account on the same computer as Alice, in the same mail client! So it assumes Alice and Bob are *the same person*, and removes Bob from the reply.

Is there any way to disable this very inconvenient software bug?

Comment: Very very simply - don't share accounts. They're not made to be shared.

Comment: You mean, set up separate users at the OS level? So Alice and Bob have to log out and in to share a computer?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: [Fast user switching](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18897) is pretty fast. You don't even have to log out.

Comment: Really helpful responses on here! NOT... I agree with original poster - there should be an option to turn this on/off so you can reply all and it maintains the original recipients even if those accounts are on the same computer.